Open LWC link to record in a new Lightning Tab
I'm writing this simple LWC to show a list of cases related to the same Account of the currently open case. I've set the Case Number column in the data table to be a link to the case record (highlighted in yellow).
The problem is the link opens in a new browser tab, I'd want the link to open in a new Lightning tab, or focus on that if already open (highlighted in green, doesn't matter which one).

This is my JS code, the Apex controller simply returns a list of records
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getRelatedCases from '@salesforce/apex/CaseRelatedCasesController.getRelatedCases';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CASE_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Case.AccountId";

const CASE_FIELDS = [CASE_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD];

const columns = [
    {label: 'Case', fieldName: 'nameUrl', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber' }, target: '_blank'}, sortable: true },
    {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'AccountId'},
    {label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'Subject'},
    {label: 'Priority', fieldName: 'Priority'},
    {label: 'Date Opened', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date'},
    {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status'},
];

export default class RelatedCases extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track columns = columns;
    @track cases;
    @track error;
    parentAccountId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: CASE_FIELDS })
    caseRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.parentAccountId = data.fields.AccountId.value;
            
            getRelatedCases({ parentAccountId: this.parentAccountId })
                .then(result => {
                    this.cases = result.map(row => ({
                        ...row,
                        nameUrl: `/${row.Id}`
                    }));
                    this.error = null;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.cases = [];
                    console.log('@@@ ERROR Getting related cases!' + error.body.message);
                });
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('@@@ ERROR Getting record! ' + error.body.message);
        }
    }
}


You can use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-workspace-api to achieve this.

Thanks for your question.
The reason your link is opening to a new browser tab is because of the target: '_blank' in the typeAttributes for the Case column. Removing your target: '_blank' will get the output you were expecting.
const columns = [
    {label: 'Case', fieldName: 'nameUrl', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber' } }, sortable: true },
    {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'AccountId'},
    {label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'Subject'},
    {label: 'Priority', fieldName: 'Priority'},
    {label: 'Date Opened', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date'},
    {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status'},
];


Thank you! It works perfectly

Sure thing! Glad it worked
